# Administrator Child Account with no 'Add/Edit/Remove Users' Permissions in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, parental-controls

I already made an administrator child account in Windows 10 but it still has capabilities to add/edit/remove users in the PC. I want to restrict it from the said capability but still be able to do administrative tasks such as installing and more. Do you have any idea on how to implement it on Windows 10?

My purpose of doing so is the child account is restricted to access some websites but because of the capability to add, edit, remove user, he can still access the restricted websites by  creating a new account. That's the reason why I want to remove the said functionality and let him still be allowed to install or uninstall programs.

Comment: An administrator cannot be limited.

Comment: @harrymc --> Is there any way I can get around with this?

Comment: Not that I know - if you give an account permission to elevate, this means unlimited powers. It would be easier to buy your child another computer, with a mechanism to rollback to an acceptable state.